# Instalação de Xamarin em Windows 7

Tags: windows, xamarin, instalador

Gostaria de instalar a ferramenta Xamarin para desenvolvimento mobile. Meu sistema operacional é o Windows 7. É possível instalar essa ferramenta no Windows 7 ou só no 10 ou versões superiores do Windows?

Comment: [Xamarin.Android Manual Installation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Precisa do Windows 7 para o básico, do 8.1 para Xamarin.Forms Windows e do 10 para Xamarin.Forms UWP, conforme a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 0):

É possível instalar o Xamarin no Windows 7 desde que você esteja com seu sistema atualizado com Service Pack, porém, recomendo você ter o Windows 10 Pro ou Enterprise, pois, a maioria dos cenários da plataforma Windows irão necessitar. Eu realizei um post  para auxiliar na instalação e configuração do Xamarim , segue o endereço  ;)

http://juniorporfirio.com.br/maratona-xamarin-instalacao-e-configuracao/